# Unable to get classes in Framework

Tags: ios, swift, swift-framework

I have created an iOS framework sample for testing after reading many article which pretty much sums up to following steps.

1. Create a new framework using XCode wizard.
2. Create a class
3. Build the framework.
4. Drag and Add to project where you want to use.

import Foundation

```
public class Apple {
    public func eat() {
        print("Tasty")
    }
}
```

Framework is added successfully to the project and I am able to import it too but When I try to access `'Apple'` class I get this `Use of unresolved identifier 'Apple'` as error.

I looked into the imported framework folder in XCode project navigator there I found

```
--abc.framework
  --Headers
    --abc-Swift.h
    --abc.h
```

I don't know what I am missing.

Framework Directory Structure

```
--abc
  --abc
    --abc.h
    --Info.plist
    --Apple.swift
  --Products
    --abc.framework
```

Note: I did not made any change to header files.
Please share links if you have.

UPDATE for generated file when i import the framework

abc.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//! Project version number for abc.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double abcVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for abc.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char abcVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <abc/PublicHeader.h>
```

abc-swift.h

```
// Generated by Apple Swift version 4.2.1 (swiftlang-1000.11.42 clang-1000.11.45.1)
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wgcc-compat"

#if !defined(__has_include)
# define __has_include(x) 0
#endif
#if !defined(__has_attribute)
# define __has_attribute(x) 0
#endif
#if !defined(__has_feature)
# define __has_feature(x) 0
#endif
#if !defined(__has_warning)
# define __has_warning(x) 0
#endif

#if __has_include(<swift/objc-prologue.h>)
# include <swift/objc-prologue.h>
#endif

#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wauto-import"
#include <objc/NSObject.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#if !defined(SWIFT_TYPEDEFS)
# define SWIFT_TYPEDEFS 1
# if __has_include(<uchar.h>)
#  include <uchar.h>
# elif !defined(__cplusplus)
typedef uint_least16_t char16_t;
typedef uint_least32_t char32_t;
# endif
typedef float swift_float2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef float swift_float3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef float swift_float4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
typedef double swift_double2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef double swift_double3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef double swift_double4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
typedef int swift_int2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef int swift_int3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef int swift_int4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
typedef unsigned int swift_uint2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef unsigned int swift_uint3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef unsigned int swift_uint4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_PASTE)
# define SWIFT_PASTE_HELPER(x, y) x##y
# define SWIFT_PASTE(x, y) SWIFT_PASTE_HELPER(x, y)
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_METATYPE)
# define SWIFT_METATYPE(X) Class
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS_PROPERTY)
# if __has_feature(objc_class_property)
#  define SWIFT_CLASS_PROPERTY(...) __VA_ARGS__
# else
#  define SWIFT_CLASS_PROPERTY(...)
# endif
#endif

#if __has_attribute(objc_runtime_name)
# define SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(X) __attribute__((objc_runtime_name(X)))
#else
# define SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(X)
#endif
#if __has_attribute(swift_name)
# define SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(X) __attribute__((swift_name(X)))
#else
# define SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(X)
#endif
#if __has_attribute(objc_method_family)
# define SWIFT_METHOD_FAMILY(X) __attribute__((objc_method_family(X)))
#else
# define SWIFT_METHOD_FAMILY(X)
#endif
#if __has_attribute(noescape)
# define SWIFT_NOESCAPE __attribute__((noescape))
#else
# define SWIFT_NOESCAPE
#endif
#if __has_attribute(warn_unused_result)
# define SWIFT_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
#else
# define SWIFT_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT
#endif
#if __has_attribute(noreturn)
# define SWIFT_NORETURN __attribute__((noreturn))
#else
# define SWIFT_NORETURN
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS)
# if __has_attribute(objc_subclassing_restricted)
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) __attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted)) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#  define SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) __attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted)) SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# else
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#  define SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# endif
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_PROTOCOL)
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL_NAMED(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_EXTENSION)
# define SWIFT_EXTENSION(M) SWIFT_PASTE(M##_Swift_, __LINE__)
#endif

#if !defined(OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER)
# if __has_attribute(objc_designated_initializer)
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER __attribute__((objc_designated_initializer))
# else
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
# endif
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_ENUM_ATTR)
# if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(enum_extensibility)
#  define SWIFT_ENUM_ATTR(_extensibility) __attribute__((enum_extensibility(_extensibility)))
# else
#  define SWIFT_ENUM_ATTR(_extensibility)
# endif
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_ENUM)
# define SWIFT_ENUM(_type, _name, _extensibility) enum _name : _type _name; enum SWIFT_ENUM_ATTR(_extensibility) SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA _name : _type
# if __has_feature(generalized_swift_name)
#  define SWIFT_ENUM_NAMED(_type, _name, SWIFT_NAME, _extensibility) enum _name : _type _name SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME); enum SWIFT_COMPILE_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_ENUM_ATTR(_extensibility) SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA _name : _type
# else
#  define SWIFT_ENUM_NAMED(_type, _name, SWIFT_NAME, _extensibility) SWIFT_ENUM(_type, _name, _extensibility)
# endif
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE)
# define SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE __attribute__((unavailable))
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE_MSG)
# define SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE_MSG(msg) __attribute__((unavailable(msg)))
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_AVAILABILITY)
# define SWIFT_AVAILABILITY(plat, ...) __attribute__((availability(plat, __VA_ARGS__)))
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_DEPRECATED)
# define SWIFT_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_DEPRECATED_MSG)
# define SWIFT_DEPRECATED_MSG(...) __attribute__((deprecated(__VA_ARGS__)))
#endif
#if __has_feature(attribute_diagnose_if_objc)
# define SWIFT_DEPRECATED_OBJC(Msg) __attribute__((diagnose_if(1, Msg, "warning")))
#else
# define SWIFT_DEPRECATED_OBJC(Msg) SWIFT_DEPRECATED_MSG(Msg)
#endif
#if __has_feature(modules)
@import ObjectiveC;
#endif

#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wproperty-attribute-mismatch"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wduplicate-method-arg"
#if __has_warning("-Wpragma-clang-attribute")
# pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wpragma-clang-attribute"
#endif
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunknown-pragmas"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wnullability"

#if __has_attribute(external_source_symbol)
# pragma push_macro("any")
# undef any
# pragma clang attribute push(__attribute__((external_source_symbol(language="Swift", defined_in="abc",generated_declaration))), apply_to=any(function,enum,objc_interface,objc_category,objc_protocol))
# pragma pop_macro("any")
#endif


SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC3abc5Apple")
@interface Apple : NSObject
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end

#if __has_attribute(external_source_symbol)
# pragma clang attribute pop
#endif
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: In which file you have class Apple ?

Comment: I have updated the directory structure. Apple.swift contains class Apple

Comment: Have you added Apple.Swift in Target Membership?

Comment: Yes that checkbox is checked.

Comment: Do I need to make change in Build phases?

Comment: did you add your framework inside the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`?

Comment: Yes on adding it to embed binary, it automatically got added to it @Koh

Comment: can you verify swift generated file in framework contain this class or not?

Comment: how to do that if you can tell me?

Comment: go to your framework file, then header file

Comment: there should be -swift.h file check your file exist there or not.

Comment: Please check the post. I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are accessing your framework in objective c. Use **@objc** If you want this class to use in objc, also one more thing your abc-swift.h missing this code that is generated by the compiler.

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC3abc5Apple")
@interface Apple : NSObject
- (void)eat;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

To Fix this inherit your class with NSObject and then rebuild your framework project.

```
@objc public class Apple: NSObject {
  @objc public func eat() {
    print("Tasty")
  }
}
```

Use in Objective c project.

```
#import <abc/abc.h> //add this in .h file

Apple *apple = [[Apple alloc] init]; //call in any method of your .m for testing
[apple eat];
```

**If still not solved check your xcode using device instead using simulator.**

Comment: you should be able to access. I tried my side on objective c project it is working. use my code.

Comment: But I am using swift only. All projects will be of swift only.

Comment: if you want to build this framework for device then you need to add script that generate universal framework, for universal framework follow this link https://medium.com/allatoneplace/writing-custom-universal-framework-in-xcode-9-and-ios-11-7a63a2ce024a

Comment: First half of it is achieved however I am not able use class in Swift. I am using device only

Comment: This framework is not for device, follow the tutorial that i refer to you to make it work for device as well.

Comment: Or when you build framework choose device after that copy that framework to your project. That’s all

Comment: change in the name solved the issue. Name starting with capital letter solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with me was most probably the name used for framework.

Summarizing how to create framework.

1. Name of framework should start with caps letter.
2. Follow all steps mentioned in question statement. Where class should be like this in case of swift

   import Foundation

   ```
   public class Test {

       public init() {} // required if you want to instantiate it otherwise an error will be thrown on compilation

       public func isPass() {
           print("You are pass")
       }
   }
   ```

If you want to extend the accessibility in objective-c then follow @ShauketSheikh answer

```
import Foundation

    @objc public class Test {

        @objc public init() {}

        @objc public func isPass() {
            print("You are pass")
        }
    }
```

I tried with real device without any extra script and code and I was able to run it. So I am not sure if scripts are required or not for running on devices.

Comment: Thank you! Had a lower case letter and nothing indicated that was an issue

Answer (score 0):

Made a singleton object of your class and use it to access your functions.
Like:

```
import Foundation
public class Apple {
    public static let sharedInstance = Apple()
    public func eat() {
        print("Tasty")
    }
}
```

Now where you want to access this function use it like this:

```
Apple.sharedInstance.eat()
```

Comment: I am not able to access the class 'Apple' so how can I access its sharedInstance?

Comment: Are you able to 'import YourFramework' in Class or its saying 'No Module found 'YourFramework''.?

Comment: Yes I am able to import it. But class is not available